# Postgres databases with different encoding

Tags: database, postgresql, encoding, multiple-databases

I tried to create databases with different encoding in postgres (I'm using PgAdmin as my database manager), but when I try to create a database with non UTF8 encoding, PgAdmin shows me an error saying that I can't create the database because it does not match my current locale "Portuguese_Brazil_1252" and that the LC_Ctype configuration requires encoding "WIN1252".

How do I configure that in PostGres? I'm running it under a locale test server with windows XP (not my choice). Is it possible to create databases with different encoding or that behavior is a PostGres limitation? Anyone here already had success managing that?

Thanks

Comment: can you tell us exactly your CREATE command in sql format (available in PgAdmin in the SQL tab) and the exact error message?

Comment: Let's just use `CREATE DATABASE test ENCODING 'latin1';`

Comment: Error message: `ERROR:  encoding LATIN1 does not match server's locale Portuguese_Brazil_1252
DETAIL:  The server's LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding WIN1252.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createdatabase.html):

> The character set encoding specified
>   for the new database must be
>   compatible with the chosen locale
>   settings (LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE). If
>   the locale is C (or equivalently
>   POSIX), then all encodings are
>   allowed, but for other locale settings
>   there is only one encoding that will
>   work properly. [...]
>
> The encoding and locale settings must
>   match those of the template database,
>   except when template0 is used as
>   template.

You should be able to use to create your database by either (or both):

- specifying `template0` as your template (instead of the default template1)
- specifying a correct LC_COLLATE (try to use LC_COLLATE = 'C')
- specifying a correct LC_CTYPE = (try to use LC_CTYPE = 'C' also)

You should add these settings to your CREATE statement (and PgAdmin lets you do it from the main form window)

If you don't know about template0/template1 and want to know, [read here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)

Comment: For a sake of sanity (since I never configured PostGres in windows) I just reinstalled PostGres, choosing the Posix compatible option during setup. Thanks for clarifying that.