# import data from excel to postgres in python using pyodbc

Tags: python, excel, postgresql, unicode, pyodbc

I am importing data from **MS-Excel** to **PostgreSQL** in `python(2.6)` using `pyodbc`.

**The problem faced is:**

There are characters like `left single quotation mark(ANSI hex code : 0x91)`, etc in the excel source. Now, when it is import into PostgreSQL using pyodbc, it terminates and gives the error `DatabaseError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x91`.

**What I tried:** I used `decode('unicode_escape')` for the time being. But, this cannot be done as this simply removes/escapes the concerned character.

**Alternate trial:** Decode initially, Unicode everywhere and then Encode later when needed from database. This can also not be done due to the expanse of the project at hand.

Please suggest me some method/procedure/in-built functions to accomplish the task.

Comment: Don't know if this answer your question. But you might find [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/964825/146792) of some use.

Comment: Hey, thanx mac for your efforts. I read that and tried using encode('utf-8') but the following error comes up : `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out the real encoding of the source document. It might be `WIN1251`. Either transcode it (for instance with [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)) or set the `client_encoding` of PostgreSQL accordingly.

If you don't have a setting in `pyodbc` (which I don't know), you can always issue a plain SQL command:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'WIN1251';
```

More in the chapter ["Automatic Character Set Conversion Between Server and Client"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/multibyte.html#AEN32070) of the manual.

Comment: Hey,Erwin. Could we change the already created database's encoding to the required/said encoding?

Comment: @SandipAgarwal: No. It is possible to create a new database (based on template0) in the same db cluster with a different encoding, but the encoding must be compatible with your locale settings, which narros it down. [Here is a related posting on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956163/postgres-databases-with-different-encoding) I am not convinced this would be a good idea to fix your problem.